# error like "Object of class std Class could not be converted to string"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

This is my controller

```
function index()
    {
        $name_list = DB::table('customers')
            ->groupBy('first_name')
            ->get(); 
      $name_list2 = DB::table('customers')
      ->where('first_name', $name_list)->first();

     return view('dynamic_field')->with('name_list2',$name_list2); 
    }
```

This is my view i am retriving this in javascript.

```
@foreach($name_list2 as $name)
        '<option value="{{ $name->first_name}}">{{ $name->first_name }}</option>'+
        @endforeach
```

Comment: You are using `first()`.It will take only one entry..So don't need to use `foreach()` in view.`foreach` used when you have a collection to print..

Comment: but i have used foreach in view

Comment: check the answer..if you are passing `$name_list` to view,you could have to use `foreach()`..But in case of `$name_list2` no need of `foreach()`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `foreach` `$name_list2` as this is a single record being fetched from the database as per your query.

You can try this without using `foreach`:

```php
{{ $name->first_name}}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: i removed foreach  but is not working '<option value="">{{ $name_list2->first_name}}</option>'+ but same error

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by this query? `$name_list2 = DB::table('customers')->where('first_name', $name_list)->first();`

Comment: i am trying to get dynamic dependent select box through query

Comment: I am not so sure about your requirements however the `where()` clause of your query isn't correct.

Comment: If you can show us your desired result, it will help.

Comment: oh please tell me where clause i am new to this laravel i need to write where first_name= $$name_list

Comment: I think i used wrong logic this donot work as i need dynamic dependent select box

Answer (score 0):

You are using `first()`.It will take only one entry..So don't need to use `foreach()` in view.`foreach()` used when you have a collection to print..

You can use `$name_list2` as

```
@if(isset($name_list2))
  {{$name_list2->first_name}}
@endif
```

No need of `foreach()`

Comment: '<option value="">{{ $name_list2->first_name}}</option>'+ i used like this but same error

Comment: Use `<option value="{{ $name_list2->first_name}}"></option>`

Comment: This option value i am using in javascrtipt

Comment: can you check whether the value is coming to the frontend or not.

Comment: Try `var option = "<option value='"+{{$name_list2->first_name}}+"'>"+{{$name_list2->first_name}}+"</option>"; `  Then append option to dropdown..`          $("#district").append(option); `

Comment: In controller put a `dd($name_list2)` to see whether it contains data or not.